# Is it legal to throw the same exception for different reasons?

Tags: c#, exception

This a code is 10 years old, without error handling. The code comes from a simple script interpreter without parser or scanner, I'm trying catch all errors in the interpreter and return a suitable error with error message.

```
    //..
    //...
    // <exception cref = "ErrorInScriptException">Wrong number of tokens.</exception>
    // <exception cref = "ErrorInScriptException">Variable not found.</exception>
    // <exception cref = "ErrorInScriptException">Variable type is not string.</exception>
    // <param name = "splitScriptLine">Split script line to be interpreted.</param>
    private void MakeString(IList<string> splitScriptLine)
    {
        //check minimum of 3 tokens
        if (Tokens < 3)
        {
            throw CreateErrorInScriptException("IDS_Invalid_Token");
        }

        var dummy = string.Empty;

        //read strings
        for (var z = 2; z < Tokens; z++)
        {
            dummy = dummy + ReadStringToken(splitScriptLine[z]);
        }

        var variable = VariableList[splitScriptLine[1], FileIncludeLevel];

        //no string var detected
        if (variable == null)
        {
            throw CreateErrorInScriptException("IDS_116");
        }

        //write new string to destination var
        if (variable.Identifier.Equals(splitScriptLine[1]))
        {
            //variable found
            if (variable.VariableType !=
                VariableType.String)
            {
                throw CreateErrorInScriptException("IDS_113");
            }

            variable.Value = dummy;
            variable.IsVarString = true;
        }
    }
```

Note: as shown in code above, I'm throwing the ErrorInScriptException in three cases, I change only the message.

```
[Serializable]
public class ErrorInScriptException : UniLoadApplicationException
{
    #region Constructors

    public ErrorInScriptException(string error)
        : base(error)
    {
    }

    #endregion Constructors


    #region Properties

    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    public string ScriptLine { get; set; }

    #endregion Properties
}



/// <summary>
///   Creates a script error.
/// </summary>
/// <param name = "message">Message to be shown.</param>
/// <returns>ErrorInScriptException or the script error.</returns>
protected Exception CreateErrorInScriptException(string message)
{
    var ex = new ErrorInScriptException(message)
             {
                ScriptLine = CurrentScriptLine,
                LineNumber = CurrentLineNumber,
                FileName = CurrentFileName,
                ErrorCode = message
             };
        ex.Data["Info"] = new ExceptionInfo(ErrorLevel.Error, message)
                      {
                        ExitApplication = false
                      };
        return ex;
}
```

Comment: @jgauffin - It is not clear to me what `ErrorInScriptException("IDS_Invalid_Token")` is.  It could be a custom exception or it could be a function call.  If it was a custom exception I would expect there to be a `new` keyword.  If it is not a custom exception his question changes significantly.  If the OP had gone to the trouble to compile and present correct code it would be easier to help him.  Thus my comment.

Comment: @Hogan: The question states `Is it legal to throw the same exception for different reasons`. It doesn't matter if `ErrorInScriptException` is an exception or an method. It is the same exception either case.

Comment: @jgauffin - if it is a method then we don't really know what is being thrown since it is some mysterious return value of a function.  It goes to what became clear in your answer, the OP is not providing correct or useful information.

Comment: @Hogan: Still. The question is about if it's OK to throw the same exception but for different reasons (as the title says). Why should we then assume that the code does something else? And why is it relevant? He didn't ask us to fix or comment the code. If you need more information to answer the question, state that. Do not just say `Does this compile`. It doesn't explain what you are looking for.

Comment: Nit picking, but the "ErrorIn" part of your class name is redundant, you've already got "Exception" in the class name. What is wrong with just calling it "ScriptException" or "CDDScriptException"?

Comment: Thanks code updated. my idea was any error come from the user script is a script error watever is the error, instated to make 100 exception type class. The erorr source is always comes from the user (script writer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually ok. However, if you intend those exceptions to be caught and dealt with by code (instead of just signalling an error that the user has to deal with), you might want to create appropriate subclasses that detail the kind of error.

I.e.

```
class InvalidTokenException : ErrorInScriptException {}
class NoStringVarException : ErrorInScriptException {}
...
```

But unless those exceptions are intended for code to react to different errors differently I don't think this makes much sense. To a user the exception message is relevant and that could be achieved with any Exception class.

Comment: I do that later in the controller and then send it to the UI.

Comment: In this case maybe i will get about 100 exceptions, The problem the code come from the user () he can write everything VAR XXX = 5, Do you think I must rewrite the whole code and make a real parser and scanner or the code can live with this workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you throwing exceptions?

I don't see a reason to why you should (if you are going to do it as in your example).

- You don't give the user a chance to handle the exception as you are using the same exception for all errors.
- You do not provide any context information which will aid the user in finding where in the script the error is.

I would at least provide context information like `throw new ErrorInScriptException("Line 312 is missing a colon");`

**Update in response to comment**

You should have provided that information in the question.

I think your handling is fine since you add context information. Unless the user of your script interpreter will try to handle the errors. In that case, you should provide more specific exceptions.

Comment: @user1035640 - Please put that code in the original question -- it will easier to read and it will make the question better.